# Sending Request 2.0 app-generated request to other than "/me"

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to send app-generated request using either JS SDK or graph API but I am not successful and desperate. Issue is that when I am sending request to currently logged user, everything is ok, but when I try to send to different user (even this user already authorized my app) I receive OAuth exception "#2 User can't send this request: Unknown error", sometimes "Failed to send any app requests".

My app has Request 2.0 enabled and is authorized with publish_stream, read_stream and user_about_me permissions. Same error messages I described are shown even in Graph API explorer.

Exactly same issue is described here using JS SDK:
[Sending an App Generated Request with the JavaScript SDK](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7496981/sending-an-app-generated-request-with-the-javascript-sdk)

... and here using Graph API:
[Posting app generated apprequest to other facebook users in Java](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7309950/posting-app-generated-apprequest-to-other-facebook-users-in-java)

Please help.

Comment: how do you select the user to whom you want to send the request?, and the code that you are using?

Comment: Using JS SDK like this:
FB.api( "/" + recipient + "/apprequests", "POST", {     message: "Notification Message",     data: "Notification data" }, function( response ) {     console.log( response ); } );

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending an App Generated Request with the JavaScript SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496981/sending-an-app-generated-request-with-the-javascript-sdk)

Comment: @genesis: They are duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

If you want send a request to a user, you should POST to the Graph API '/user_id/apprequests' using an App Access Token (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#applogin). This call is to design to be executed server-side as you don't want to share your App Access Token:

```
curl -F 'access_token=APP_ACCESS_TOKEN' \
-F 'message=From the app to the user.' \
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/apprequests
```

The same can be achieve using the User Access Token from the recipient (USER_ID) only:

```
curl -F 'access_token=USER_ACCESS_TOKEN' \
-F 'message=From the app to the user.' \
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/apprequests
```

In the JS SDK, if no Access Token field is added, the default Access Token will be of the logged in user. Knowing that, the above call which send the a request to the logged in user, will be:

```
FB.api('/me/apprequests', 'POST',  {message: 'From the app to the user.'});
```

The first call can also be done with the JS SDK, by adding the App Access Token in the parameters. However, this is a DO NOT USE case as you don't want to share your App Access token client-side.